# IEnumString.Next() always returns 0 items fetched

Tags: c#, vb.net, security, com, pinvoke

I'm p/invoking `InternetSecurityManager.GetZoneMappings()` in order to get a list of safe sites from my Intranet Zone, and the `Next()` method on the returned `IEnumString` object always reports that zero sites were fetched, even though there were.

Here's my code, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5724220):

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes

Public Class Test
  Private Shared ReadOnly CLSID_InternetSecurityManager As New Guid("7b8a2d94-0ac9-11d1-896c-00c04fb6bfc4")
  Private ReadOnly InternetSecurityManager As IInternetSecurityManager
  Private ReadOnly SecurityManager As Object

  Private Const URLZONE_LOCAL_MACHINE As UInteger = &H0
  Private Const URLZONE_INTRANET As UInteger = URLZONE_LOCAL_MACHINE + 1
  Private Const URLZONE_TRUSTED As UInteger = URLZONE_INTRANET + 1
  Private Const URLZONE_INTERNET As UInteger = URLZONE_TRUSTED + 1
  Private Const URLZONE_UNTRUSTED As UInteger = URLZONE_INTERNET + 1

  Public Sub New
    Dim oType As Type

    oType = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(CLSID_InternetSecurityManager)

    Me.SecurityManager = Activator.CreateInstance(oType)
    Me.InternetSecurityManager = Me.SecurityManager

    Me.GetSites()
  End Sub

  Private Function GetSites() As List(Of String)
    Dim nItemsFetched As ULong
    Dim oEnumString As IEnumString
    Dim oSites As List(Of String)
    Dim aItems As String()

    oEnumString = Nothing

    Me.InternetSecurityManager.GetZoneMappings(URLZONE_INTRANET, oEnumString, 0)

    oSites = New List(Of String)
    aItems = New String(0) {}

    Do
      oEnumString.Next(1, aItems, nItemsFetched)

      If aItems.First Is Nothing Then
        Exit Do
      Else
        oSites.Add(aItems.First)
      End If
    Loop

    Return oSites
  End Function
End Class
```

It runs and it does enumerate the list correctly, but I'd like to clean it up a bit by responding appropriately to the value of `nItemsFetched` (rather than the present rather cumbersome check for `Nothing`).

It seems that managed code samples of `GetZoneMappings()` are pretty scarce out there. Plenty of signatures, but no usage. I couldn't find any (in fact, for all my searching this might be the only one). After some serious digging, though, I did manage to put my thumb on the `EnumString` sample linked above.

Here's my `IInternetSecurityManager` interface, gleaned from [p/invoke.net](https://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Interfaces/IInternetSecurityManager.html):

```
Imports System
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes

<ComImport, Guid("79EAC9EE-BAF9-11CE-8C82-00AA004BA90B"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)>
Public Interface IInternetSecurityManager
  <PreserveSig>
  Function SetSecuritySite(
  <[In]> pSite As IntPtr) As Integer

  <PreserveSig>
  Function GetSecuritySite(
  <Out> pSite As IntPtr) As Integer

  <PreserveSig>
  Function MapUrlToZone(
  <[In], MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> pwszUrl As String, <Out> ByRef pdwZone As UInteger, dwFlags As UInteger) As Integer

  <PreserveSig>
  Function GetSecurityId(
  <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> pwszUrl As String,
  <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)> pbSecurityId As Byte(), ByRef pcbSecurityId As UInteger, dwReserved As UInteger) As Integer

  <PreserveSig>
  Function ProcessUrlAction(
  <[In], MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> pwszUrl As String, dwAction As UInteger, <Out> ByRef pPolicy As Byte, cbPolicy As UInteger, pContext As Byte, cbContext As UInteger, dwFlags As UInteger, dwReserved As UInteger) As Integer

  <PreserveSig>
  Function QueryCustomPolicy(
  <[In], MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> pwszUrl As String, ByRef guidKey As Guid, ByRef ppPolicy As Byte, ByRef pcbPolicy As UInteger, ByRef pContext As Byte, cbContext As UInteger, dwReserved As UInteger) As Integer

  <PreserveSig>
  Function SetZoneMapping(dwZone As UInteger, <[In], MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> lpszPattern As String, dwFlags As UInteger) As Integer

  <PreserveSig>
  Function GetZoneMappings(dwZone As UInteger, <Out> ByRef ppenumString As IEnumString, dwFlags As UInteger) As Integer
End Interface
```

I tried building an `IEnumString` interface based on [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3792/C-does-Shell-Part-4), but I only ran into problems with that. At least the native call completes and returns data. I just want to be able to know when the data stops coming.

How can I get `EnumString.Next()` to correctly return the number of items it fetches?

Comment: Next() returns an HRESULT value, 0 is S_OK which means it returns something in rgelt. You must allocate aItems to an array of 1 element at least before call and read the first element in this array after success call (nFetched should  be 1). Look at the native documentation about it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/nf-objidl-ienumstring-next

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm doing. See the code above. I'm initializing a `String()` array with a length of 1 and sending that to the `Next()` call. I'm then evaluating it after the call to retrieve my data. But in all cases, `nItemsFetched` always returns zero—even when data is returned. I'm getting the data I expect—currently my zone has two entries—but `nItemsFetched` falsely tells me that I have none. That's the crux of the problem.

Comment: Aha. The `HRESULT` gets set to `S_FALSE` when the data runs out. That's a workaround, but it'll do. Bundle it up as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: this is not a "workaround", that's all how it works

Comment: I'm not sure if you can use auto-generated COM wrappers for any of this; if you can and you want to, you can hand-edit the generated IL from the interop library to enable getting the raw HRESULT instead of having the internals check for SUCCEEDED or FAILED and throw on FAILED.  If you need to know what to do, I can follow up with the details.

Comment: @Craig — Yes, this sounds very interesting. How would a person get started?

Comment: If you have a type library, you can use the tlbimp utility to create an interop dll.  If you need to edit the automatically generated interfaces, you can use ildasm on the generated dll, edit the resulting il file, then use ilasm to create the updated file.  You would have this interop library as a reference in your project, and go through that.

Comment: To be able to get the HRESULT for a particular routine, you would find it in the IL, change it from `instance void` to `instance int32 marshal( error )`, and add `preservesig` to the flags at the end of the declaration (in my case, between `managed` and `internalcall`).  I don't remember now whether I got the instructions for this from MSDN, Stack Overflow, or some other internet source.  You can manually call `Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR` in you code if you detect a failure HRESULT to mimic what the marshaller would normally do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Next()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/nf-objidl-ienumstring-next) returns an HRESULT value, so 0 is `S_OK` (success) which means it returns something in `rgelt`.

So,

1. you must allocate `aItems` to an array of (at least) 1 element before call;
2. optionally, you can pass a non null pointer to the `pceltFetched`. if you pass null, you cannot determine how many items where read;
3. the call should return `S_OK` (0) if something was read, `S_FALSE` (1) if not all was requested was read (and possibly something else in error cases) which in the `celt` = 1 case is the same a "this was the last item in the enumeration".

So, your code can be written like this:

```
Do

    Dim ret = oEnumString.Next(1, aItems, IntPtr.Zero)
    If ret <> 0 Then Exit Do

    oSites.Add(aItems.First)
Loop
```

Or like this if you want to use the `pceltFetched` argument. This is rarely needed, only when `celt` > 1 (when the return value just say that not everything was read) which is not always supported by enum sources either, so everyone always uses `celt` = 1...

```
Dim fetchedPtr As IntPtr
fetchedPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(Of Integer)()) ' or AllocCoTaskMem
Dim fetched As Integer

Do

    oEnumString.Next(1, aItems, fetchedPtr)
    fetched = Marshal.ReadInt32(fetchedPtr)
    If fetched <> 1 Then Exit Do

    oSites.Add(aItems.First)
Loop

Marshal.FreeHGlobal(fetchedPtr)
```